# Object.Create calling function with prototype

Tags: javascript

Oke, I have this working:

```
const personProto2 = {
  calAge() {
    console.log(2021 - this.birthday);
  },
};
```

```
const rein = Object.create(personProto2);
rein.name = "Rein";
rein.birthday = 1945;
rein.calAge();
```

But if I do this:

```
const Person = function (name, birthday) {
  this.name = name;
  this.birthday = birthday;
};

Person.prototype.calAge = function () {
  console.log(2021 - this.birthday);
};
```

```
const rein = Object.create(Person);
rein.name = "Rein";
rein.birthday = 1945;
rein.prototype.calAge();
```

It doesn't work. But a function is also a object. And a object has also a prototype.

So why the second example doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you meant using `new` when creating a blank, plain JavaScript object.

The `new` operator lets you create an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function. now, you can call the `calAge` method.

```js
function Person(name, birthday) {
  this.name = name;
  this.birthday = birthday;
};

Person.prototype.calAge = function () {
  console.log(2021 - this.birthday);
};

const rein = new Person("Rein", 1945);
rein.calAge();
```

Comment: Thank you. Ah, oke. So a function is an object. But function name(){} doens't create a object with Object.create. And {} with Object.create createds an object.